# Interpreting bivariate/multivariate probit model (Rstan implementation)

Tags: probit, multivariate-regression, stan

I'm having trouble with inference from the posterior predictive distribution I've generated from a multivariate probit model I constructed using Rstan. My primary interest in the model is to estimate the probability of co-occurrence, with uncertainty, for correlated responses after having accounted for independent variables (e.g., environmental predictors in the case of species habitat modeling). I created some toy data for the bivariate (reponse) problem to try to (1) make sure the Stan model is recovering the parameters, and (2) get a clearer understanding of how to go about inference, particularly with regard to the joint vs. marginal posterior as it relates to estimating co-occurrence.

At this point, I believe that the Stan code is correct, as it consistently recovers the parameters from simulated data and also gives sensible results for the betas and correlation (Omega) for real data (with up to 20 responses). Likewise, the Stan output matches very closely the output from a maximum likelihood implmentation using the bprobit call from the ZeligChoice package. At this point, I'll post the basic Stan model and data simulation I used to study it.

Stan code:

```
data {
 int<lower=1> K;
 int<lower=1> D;
 int<lower=1> N;
 matrix<lower=-1,upper=1>[N,D] y;
 matrix[N,K] x;
}
parameters {
 vector[D] beta0;
 matrix[K,D] beta;
 cholesky_factor_corr[D] L_Omega;
 matrix<lower=0>[N,D] abs_ystar; //latent variable
}
transformed parameters {
 matrix[N,D] z;
 z = (y .* (abs_ystar));
}
model {
 beta0 ~ normal(0, 5);
 to_vector(beta) ~ normal(0, 2.5);
 L_Omega ~ lkj_corr_cholesky(2);
 { 
  matrix[N,D] beta_x;
  for (d in 1:D)
    beta_x[,d] = beta0[d] + (x * beta[,d]);
  for (n in 1:N)
    target += multi_normal_cholesky_lpdf(z[n,] | beta_x[n,], L_Omega);
  }
}
generated quantities {
 matrix[D,N] z_new;
 corr_matrix[D] Omega;
 Omega = multiply_lower_tri_self_transpose(L_Omega);
{
  matrix[D,N] beta_x;
   for (d in 1:D)
    beta_x[d,] = beta0[d] + (x * beta[,d])';
   for (n in 1:N)
    z_new[,n] = multi_normal_cholesky_rng(beta_x[,n], L_Omega);
  }
}
```

And here is the data sim:

```
K <- 3
D <- 2
N <- 500

x <- matrix(rnorm(N*(K-1), 0, 1), N, K-1)
MyStd <- function(x){ (x-mean(x))/(sd(x)*2)}
x <- as.matrix(apply(x, 2, MyStd)) #Standardize inputs ala Gelman et al. 2006

beta <- matrix(c(0.5, 1, -1, 0.5, -1, 1), 3, 2) # intercepts and 2 betas per response
Omega <- matrix(c(1, -0.6, -0.6, 1), 2, 2)
xBeta <- x %*% beta[2:K,]
LinPred <- cbind((beta[1,1] + xBeta[,1]), (beta[1,2] + xBeta[,2])) #add intercepts

z <- matrix(NA, N, D)
for (n in 1:N) {
  z[n,] <- mvrnorm(1, LinPred[n,], Omega)
 }

y <- ifelse(z > 0, 1, 0)
```

Stan output (2000 post-warmup draws):

```
               mean  se_mean  sd      2.5%      25%      50%      75%    97.5% n_eff Rhat
beta0[1]       0.46    0.00  0.06     0.33     0.41     0.45     0.50     0.58   722 1.00
beta0[2]       0.58    0.00  0.07     0.44     0.53     0.58     0.62     0.71   613 1.01
beta[1,1]      1.17    0.01  0.14     0.89     1.07     1.16     1.26     1.44   544 1.00
beta[1,2]     -1.11    0.01  0.14    -1.39    -1.21    -1.11    -1.02    -0.82   353 1.00
beta[2,1]     -0.98    0.01  0.14    -1.25    -1.07    -0.98    -0.88    -0.71   470 1.01
beta[2,2]      1.16    0.01  0.14     0.89     1.06     1.16     1.26     1.43   448 1.01
Omega[1,1]     1.00    0.00  0.00     1.00     1.00     1.00     1.00     1.00  2000  NaN
Omega[1,2]    -0.60    0.00  0.07    -0.73    -0.65    -0.61    -0.56    -0.46   233 1.01
Omega[2,1]    -0.60    0.00  0.07    -0.73    -0.65    -0.61    -0.56    -0.46   233 1.01
Omega[2,2]     1.00    0.00  0.00     1.00     1.00     1.00     1.00     1.00   986 1.00
lp__       -1603.29    2.51 37.07 -1674.73 -1628.48 -1603.76 -1578.20 -1528.46   218 1.01
```

Where I think I may be getting confused is with interpreting the posterior (predictive) distribution produced. Take this plot of the joint distribution for z_new[ , 1, 1] vs. z_new[ , 2, 1] :

[image: Latent z1@N1 vs Latent z2@N1]

My understanding was that the marginal estimates could be summarized by taking the sum of the posterior values for either z[ , 1, 1] or z[ , 2, 1] that are greater than zero, but that multiplying these marginals doesn't give the probability of co-occurrence. Rather, the estimate of probability for the joint occurrence (i.e., prob of co-occurrence that I'm most interested in) is summarized by the sum of points in the upper right quadrant divided by the total number of points. My understanding is that the betas control the marginals (e.g., environmentally induced correlation), whereas Omega determines co-occurrence due to response interactions (or unmeasured predictors).

On to the primary source of my quandary: I was under the impression that the multivariate probit would outperform a piecewise approach using, say, glm to construct individual models for each y and then "stacking" predictions to estimate co-occurrence or, when D > 2, richness. However, in my experience so far with the bivariate case, using various values for betas and Omegas, this doesn't seem to consistently be the case. I should add that the bprobit performance in this regard has been pretty much identical to the Stan model. That is, in most cases, the co-occurrence estimates are very similar to the piecewise approach, even when Omega is quite large in any direction. There seem to be few cases where the multivariate parameterization prevails, and for those I haven't quite put my finger on why that is (e.g., special cases of beta and Omega?).

Here is how I estimated prob of coocurrence from the ppd in the current example:

```
predict_cooc <- rep(NA, N)
for(i in 1:N){
  predict_cooc[i] <- sum(la$z_new[,1,i] > 0 & la$z_new[,2,i] > 0)
}
```

And here is a contingency table of that result for N=1 to 500:

```
table(data.frame(cbind(predict_cooc > 1000, ifelse(rowSums(y[,1:2])==2, 1, 0))))

      X2
   X1    0   1
      0 338 162
```

Thus, in this admittedly extreme case where the betas are perfectly negatively correlated and Omega is fairly large and negative the model appears to expect 0 co-occurrences whereas, in fact, there were 162. Compare this to the piecewise approach with glm, which I expected to perform relatively poorly with such strong correlation (Omega):

```
g1 <- glm(y[,1] ~ ., data.frame(x), family=binomial(probit))
g2 <- glm(y[,2] ~ ., data.frame(x), family=binomial(probit))

table(data.frame(cbind(ifelse(rowSums(cbind(ifelse(predict(glm(y[,1] ~ ., 
 data.frame(x), family=binomial(probit)))>0, 1, 0),ifelse(predict(glm(y[,2] 
 ~ ., data.frame(x), family=binomial(probit)))>0, 1, 
 0)))==2,1,0),ifelse(rowSums(y)==2,1,0)))) #sorry for awfully cumbersome code

          X2
   X1    0   1
      0 186  71
      1 152  91
```

In conclusion, I feel that it is mostly like that I am misunderstanding something fundamental about these joint estimates (I'm obviously not a statistician by training) because my Stan model closely matches one from the manual and the results very nearly mirror those from bprobit:ZeligChoice. However, I also can't rule out that I've somehow botched the fake data sim. Whatever the case, I would be extremely grateful if someone out there could give me a nudge in the right direction because this thing has been driving me nuts for quite some time.

Comment: learning now... try to refer to https://github.com/englianhu/example-models